# Pandas business days calculation

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 columns (start date, end date). I basically want to create a new column which calculates number of business days between start and end dates.

[image]

The name of the dataframe is Fuel_Oil and I have named the new column "Bus_days"

I tried to add the following syntax:

```
Fuel_Oil["Bus_days"] = Fuel_Oil.bdate_range("pricing_start_date",'pricing_end_date')
```

but I'm getting an error.